# Determine whether or not a conjunction of logical conditions can be satisfied without looping

Tags: math, logic, equation

Other than iterating through a bunch of nested loops, how can I answer this type of combinatorial question?

```
there are two numbers E1 and E2 

E1 = A * x + B* y + C* z, and E2 = A * p + B * q + C * r

Value of A, B, C are different positive integers.

Value of x, y, z, p, q, r may be the same, and they are positive integers.
```

can we have any value for `A, B, C, x, y, z, p, q, r` such that all the following conditions will be true?

- x + y + z == p + q + r
- E1 == E2
- x != p or y != q or z != r

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: What is the context for this?  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
A=1, B=2, C=3
x=1, y=3, z=1
p=2, q=1, r=2

A*x+B*y+C*z = 1+6+3 = 10
A*p+B*q+C*r = 2+2+6 = 10

x+y+z = 5 = p+q+r
```

Comment: 0<A,B,C<50   and     
50<=x,y,z,p,q,r   and all x,y,z,p,q,r are primes  
then any solution for same condition?

Comment: A=5, B=7, C=1, x=53, y=61, z=67, p=67, q=53, r=61